# How to increase automatic height of matdialogbox in angular 5?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

```
  uploadFiles(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewFilesOrImagesComponent, {
      width: '620px',
      height : '100%',
    });
  }
```

if height 100 % UI looks like this(under upload button not necessary empty spaces)

[image]

if I put fix height in px(it makes UI scrollable)

```
  uploadFiles(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewFilesOrImagesComponent, {
      width: '620px',
      height : '250px',
    });
  }
```

[image]

I want actual this type if I SELECT File it automatic increase its height(when i choose image that time i want to increase automatic height of matdialogbox)

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use `height: auto`?

Comment: i not use height : auto i use 100%

Comment: I use height : 'auto' but i not makes scrollable matdialogbox

Comment: As Peter Kim suggests, setting `height: 'auto'` should do the trick.

Comment: @Jesper yes i do the trick height: 'auto' but when dialogbox height is more than browser that time dialog box not scrolls

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this, it will take ***complete height*** of the page for your *matdialog*

```
 uploadFiles(): void {
   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewFilesOrImagesComponent, {
        width: '100%',
        minHeight: 'calc(100vh - 90px)',
        height : 'auto'
    });
 }
```

Comment: here calc is undefined.

Comment: It must be `min-height: 'calc(100vh - 90px)'`

Comment: This is now updated to use "minHeight" instead of "min-height"

Answer (score 4):

The dialog does automatically adapt to the content as long as its html is wrappend inside `mat-dialog-content`. :

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{data.title}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>...>
<div mat-dialog-actions>...>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default max height of content of material dialog is `65vh`. It can be increased by styling `.mat-dialog-content`

```
::ng-deep {
    .mat-dialog-content {
        max-height: 90vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your dialog:

```
uploadFiles(): void {
 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewFilesOrImagesComponent, {
   panelClass: 'myClass',
 });
}
```

Then add the following style to the class in your CSS:

```
.myClass {
  max-height: 95%;
  width: 620px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```