# dynamically change width/height of a mat-dialog in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

it is possible to change dynamically the height/width of a mat-dialog according the content inside?

for example, if I have a mat-select with three options and each one shows a different number of fields below the select field, it is possible to do the dialog change size to fill the content?

I'm learning Angular and don't know if its possible. I do not have any ideias how could do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65718180/6490545

> The dialog does automatically adapt to the content as long as its html
> is wrappend inside mat-dialog-content

[Angular Material Examples](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples)

[Material Dialog Config - you can set minHeight/minWidth for dialogs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig)